# What is the primary purpose of Object Scopes DI C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Please could you help me to understand where i must use an object scopes in DI c#. 
What is the purpose of this?

```
kernel.Bind<Shogun>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: which libraries are you using? what's kernel?
where is the code used?
give us some info man!

Comment: Bother to google it yourself? https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Comment: I read this article but i still can't understand why to define a SingletonScope when i can't use interface?

Comment: SingletonScope is a lifetime management option. Binding a certain interface to a specific implementation is something completely different. You should replace Bind<Shogun>.ToSelf with Bind<IShogun>.To<Shogun> where IShogun is the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Scope aka Lifetime Scope is a very important part of every application but especially when it comes to dependency injection.

With dependency injection you not only give away the control of which implementation is created, but also when this instance is destructed.

Setting the lifetime instructs an DI container when to destruct an instance and create a new one if a new request for that type comes in.

There are several different lifetimes:

- Singleton: Exactly one instance of a certain component is created during the lifetime of the application.
- Transient: Every time an instance is needed a new one is created
- PerRequest: One instance is created and reused every request. A request could be a lot of things. For ASP.net mvc a request is typically a HTTPrequest. For a windows forms application a request is to be determined by the application, normally within a certain 'using' block.

Ninject specifics can be found here:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes